# Pandas - Converting datetime field to a specified format

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am trying to get a date time field in Pandas in the below format

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

The above code returns date time column in the below format

```
2021-11-27 03:30:00
```

I would like to get an output of `27/11/2021` `(format is dd/mm/yyyy)` and the data type of the column needs to be **datetime** and not **object**.

Comment: Where are you viewing the output? Jupyter output?

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a string, you will need to first use `pd.to_datetime`,

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then, use `.dt` datetime accessor with `strftime`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods = 60, freq='D')})

df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
```

Or use lambda function:

```
df.Date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d')).astype(int)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But I see the output suggested is still a string and not datetime